# Are the vectors of an eigenspace linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say there are multiple eigenvectors associated to a single eigenvalue for some square matrix A. And, the eigenspace is not empty. Will the vectors of the eigenspace be linearly independent? Why?

Comment: Every scalar multiple of an eigenvector will also be an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue. I.e. if $Av = \lambda v$ then $A(kv) = \lambda (kv)$.

Comment: When we use the term, "multiple eigenvectors", there is an implicit agreement that we are talking about a collection of linearly independent eigenvectors. If there are not two or more linearly independent eigenvectors associated to some particular eigenvalue, then we don't use the term, "multiple eigenvectors".

Comment: So, do you understand the situation now, stack?

Comment: Are you still here, stack?

Comment: It's not polite to ask a question, and then disappear when others try to help you, stack.

Answer (score 1):

An eigenspace is a *subspace* associated to a certain eigenvalue, therefore this is meaningless ask whether vectors of an eigenspace are linearly independent it depends of course from the  dimension of the eigenspace and from the particular set of vectors we are considering.

If we deal with an eigenspace with dimension $1$, of course any set of vectors is lineraly dependent,if we deal with an eigenspace with dimension $2$ a triple of vectors is always linear dependent but we can find infinitely many pairs of vectors linearly independent (i.e. basis for the eigenspace), and so on.